# Can moderators comment or vote on deleted posts? Can moderators answer deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, moderators, moderator-abilities

I am only curious, how the general lock on deleted posts interacts with the diamond.

Comment: Why would a moderator answer a deleted question?  If it's deleted then nobody gains anything from the answer

Comment: @Ramhound It is a theoretical "infinite weighing stone vs. unbreakable wall" question, to get a better understand on the logic of the system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Moderators can comment on deleted posts. [**In limited circumstances**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/98786), this ability allows Moderators to leave feedback or let users know why their post was deleted.

But other than that, Moderators cannot answer or vote on deleted posts.