# Do 10k+ users see the pings if they were already deleted? Do mods see them?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, notifications, deleted-answers

Consider the following scenario:

1. *User A* writes a comment to *User B*, or answers the question of *User B*.
2. This could ping *user B*, i.e. (s)he would see the comment in his inbox.
3. However, *User B* is not logged in at the time.
4. The ping is made deleted:

   - the answer of *User A* (to *User B*'s question) is deleted
   - the comment of *User A* (to *User B*'s post, or by mentioning `@UserB`) is deleted
   - the post which is commented by *User A*, is deleted (but not the comment)
5. After that, *User B* logs in.

Will he see the ping in his/her inbox?

If *User B* is a 10k+ user, in theory (s)he would see *User A*'s answer, and also his comment, if it wasn't deleted. If *User B* is a diamond moderator, (s)he could even see *User A*'s deleted comment.

I think, the most logical way would be, if *User B* would see the ping if and only if (s)he could see the post or comment addressed to him(she). But how does it actually work?

Comment: I thought everyone did. It's really annoying when you cannot read the post.

Comment: Well you’re describing a few different scenarios... some of which is answered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/307988

Comment: @Ramhound I think it may be sub-optimal, although so they will at least know, that a reaction to his/her post existed.

Comment: @Cai Thanks, it helps a lot, and also Ramhound's comment.