# Are users notified when a moderator comments on a post that is deleted?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, moderators

This is related to [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work/231990#231990) but that question does not actually answer this one... there's a comment requesting information about this on the answer but it received no response.

As an example - I have a user who posts a low quality question. It gets two downvotes. While writing a comment to explain why the question is low quality, the user deletes their own post. Because I'm a moderator, I go ahead and submit the comment, hoping that it will guide them on how to improve the post.

Are they notified of this?

- Does who deleted the post matter? For example, if the moderator comments on a post deleted by users with that privilege, will the OP get the message?
- As with the related question, is there a time frame for this or is it irrelevant?
- If a moderator deletes the post and then another one comments, will the OP see that comment?

Comment: The current top-voted [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301722/162827) seems to contradict the information given in the top-voted, accepted answer to a 2012 [status-completed] post: *[Treat comments on deleted posts from moderating users like comments from diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143640/162827)* “canned comments aren’t deleted”, and this 2014 post: [*How do notifications on deleted posts work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/162827) “only moderator comments within the last hour aren’t deleted”. Does anyone know which one is currently accurate?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, a user gets notified when a moderator comments on their deleted post. Even if the comment arrives long after the deletion. Does not matter who deleted the post.

Note: The notification will persist in the user's inbox if the moderator comments on the post *after the post is deleted*. If the moderator commented on the post prior to the post being deleted, then the inbox notification is treated like any other notification for other comments: *all* notifications for comments made prior to the post being deleted are removed from the user's inbox when the post is deleted. A moderator's comment left *after deletion* creates a new notification which persists, but which will be cleared if the post is undeleted and re-deleted.

Source: own experience of receiving such a comment.

Comment: I have the opposite experience. An Answer of mine was deleted and I didn't know about it until 17 days later accidentally stumbling across it and finding it deleted by a moderator. Also, it was deleted 2 weeks after I originally posted it, so there was no reason for me to keep monitoring it for an action like this.

Comment: @Makyen According to [an older post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/377214), comments left by the same moderator who deleted the post posted up to one hour before they deleted the post will be retained in inboxes. Is this no longer the case?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Inbox notifications were not retained in the testing we did shortly after I became a moderator. It's possible that something was flawed in our methodology or communication wasn't complete between everyone on the test, so more testing is probably reasonable. Now that I think about it, I'm unsure if we tested the specific case which you mention: where the comment is posted by the same moderator as deletes the post, but before they delete it.

Comment: @Makyen as the other person involved in [that test](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50305556), the post was already deleted when the comment was posted.

Comment: @RyanM I have it mentally checked off as also testing if the notification survived the post being deleted after the comment was placed, and that the result was that the inbox notification was removed. I'm vaguely thinking it was at a similar time, but I could be misremembering either the time or the completeness of the testing.