# Do moderators have super-ping also in comments/posts?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, moderators, super-ping

Recently I have noticed for the first time a comment by a moderator which contained `@@username`. Previously I have seen something similar in chat - I know that the mods have [superping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258038/what-is-a-superping) in chat - the ability to ping any user, even if they were not present in that chatroom (so they are not pingable by regular users using `@username`.)

I have also seen that [when a super-ping is used un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/57453110/history), the syntax `@@user-chat-id` is employed. (Although it is [rendered simply as @username](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57453110#57453110).) So the syntax `@@username` naturally reminded me of a super ping.

I have never seen something like that in a post or in a comment - so this made me curious a bit.

**Question 1.** Do moderators have ability to notify any user in a post or in a comment? (Even in situation where the user would not be notify by [the standard comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).)

It is natural to ask also this:

**Question 2.** Could implementing something like this be useful in some situations?

I will explicitly say that I am not posting this as a feature request - my personal opinion is that situation where something like this would help are going to be rather rare and there is always some kind of workaround. But since I asked whether such feature exists, this seems like a natural follow-up.

Comment: For all you know, their finger could have accidentally double-tapped the `@` key...especially since superpinging in chat works only through user IDs and not names, even though they're rendered as names.

Comment: In this case, the superping-in-comment attempt should be chalked up to a newbie mod not knowing things :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, we don't, and I don't know of a situation where it would help *moderating* the site. Perhaps on Meta, if a main site post is being discussed where user X is involved. But there's a workaround: if I want to invite them into the discussion, I'll leave a neutral comment under the post on the main site mentioning something like 'This post is being discussed on Meta' with a link.

♦ moderator comments are special in one regard: [they remain in your inbox when the post is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301713/295232).

Comment: The situation where some action of a specific is discussed on a per-site-meta was exactly what I was thinking about. But notifying the user elsewhere is probably better - if the user wasn't mentioned in the meta thread by name, this gives them more privacy. (It's up to them whether they joint the discussion - that will usually make more clear who was the user that caused the meta discussion.) I did not know about the comments by moderators remaining in the inbox - it is interesting to know.

Comment: I kinda forgot about that :D

Answer (score 6):

1. Nope
2. We rarely need to pull someone in who isn't involved. If we knew them well enough, we have ways to get in contact with them.

The use of a superping in these situations is a bit weird. Its kinda a way to pull someone aside for a private *informal* chat. It *often* starts on a post or comment thread but we don't want to keep it there.

It can also be a way to get the attention of a *specific* person - which often means a broader bidirectional communication - Which posts aren't and comments needn't be. It works great as a way to start a conversation, especially in a new room.